# how to use FetchExpression and retrievemultiple to fetch multiple pages of entities?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, workflow

I want to build a console app that can take a fetch xml query and start a workflow on all of the results using the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.

I'm using **FetchExpression** to interpret the xml string into a query, and RetireveMultiple to fetch the results.

Unfortunately **RetrieveMultiple** seems to have a limited page size of 5000.

I've worked around this in other projects using a **QueryExpression** instead, setting its PagingInfo and looping until there are NoMoreRecords, but a FetchExpression does not seem to have this paging option.

Can anyone suggest a solution to code my way out of this? or is there another way to run workflows across 1000's of records, without having to page through them all in the UI ?

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string WORKFLOW_NAME = "Do the thing";

        const string FETCH_XML_QUERY = @"<fetch version=""1.0"" output-format=""xml-                
    platform"" mapping=""logical"" distinct=""false"">
      <entity name=""new_thing"">
        <attribute name=""new_thingid"" />
        <attribute name=""new_name"" />
        <attribute name=""createdon"" />
        <order attribute=""new_name"" descending=""false"" />
        <filter type=""and"">
          <condition attribute=""statecode"" operator=""eq"" value=""0"" />
        </filter>
      </entity>
    </fetch>";

    try
    {


        var ds = new CRM.CRMService().CreateService() as OrganizationServiceProxy;

        using (var service = new CrmServiceClient(ds))
        {
            if (service.IsReady)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Connected to Dynamics 365: {ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CRM.ServiceUrl"]}");


                // Retrieve the workflow by name
                var query = new QueryExpression("workflow");
                query.ColumnSet.AddColumns("workflowid");
                query.Criteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, WORKFLOW_NAME);

                Entity workflowEntity = service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities.FirstOrDefault();
                if (workflowEntity != null)
                {


                    // Retrieve entities using FetchXML query
                    EntityCollection entityCollection = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(FETCH_XML_QUERY));


                    Console.WriteLine($"Retrieved {entityCollection.Entities.Count} entities.");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Run workflow: \"{WORKFLOW_NAME}\" ? Y or N");


                    var key = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (key.ToLower() == "y")
                    {
                        if (entityCollection.Entities.Count > 0)
                        {
                            int i = 1;
                            // Trigger the workflow for each entity
                            foreach (var entity in entityCollection.Entities)
                            {
                                service.Execute(new ExecuteWorkflowRequest
                                {
                                    WorkflowId = workflowEntity.Id,
                                    EntityId = entity.Id
                                });

                                Console.WriteLine($"{i++} of {entityCollection.Entities.Count}: Workflow {WORKFLOW_NAME} triggered for entity with ID: {entity.Id}");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("No entities found based on the query.");
                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"No workflow found by name:\"{WORKFLOW_NAME}\"");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect to Dynamics 365.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

}

Comment: 1. For fetchXml, you can use paging cookie. Read this official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/org-service/page-large-result-sets-with-fetchxml#fetchxml-and-the-paging-cookie-example
2. If your workflow enabled the "As an on-demand process", you should be able to run it in advanced find, just query the result and then click "Run Workflow" ribbon and select your workflow to run.

Comment: Thanks @raygan, i forgot the paging occurs on the entity collection, not the query. As for number 2, the advanced find doesn't let me select more than the page size, which i have mazed out at 250. I had to run a workflow on 18000 records!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FetchExpression and EntityCollection natively support paging.
Something like this should work for you:

```
EntityCollection entityCollection = null;
string pagingCookie = null;
int pageNumber = 0;

do
{
    pageNumber++;
    
    // Set Paging Cookie
    string fetchQuery = SetPagingInformation(FETCH_XML_QUERY, 1000, pageNumber, entityCollection?.PagingCookie ?? String.Empty);
    
    // Execute Fetch
    entityCollection = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchQuery));
    
    // Your existing code goes here - just gets repeated for each page
}
while (entityCollection.MoreRecords);


// Helper Method that sets paging info on fetchxml
private string SetPagingInformation(string fetchQuery, int batchSize, int page, string pagingCookie) 
{
    fetchXml = new XmlDocument();
    fetchXml.LoadXml(fetchXml);
            
    fetchXml.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("count", batchSize.ToString());
    fetchXml.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("page", page.ToString());
    fetchXml.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("paging-cookie", pagingCookie);
    
    return fetchXml.OuterXml;
}
```

The key point is that paging cookie from the entity collection can be embedded in the fetch query to support paging.  I believe there are fleshed out examples of this in the SDK

Here is a microsoft page with some more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/org-service/page-large-result-sets-with-fetchxml